# Add downloadable zip file to cms page

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, downloadable

Using Magento2.3.4 Enterprise Cloud we need to create a cms page that will list links to various zip files that will contain marketing material. My issue is where do I upload the zip file too as in what path? I tried adding the zip file to the Magento_Theme/templates directory but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the zip files to be publicly accessible links (it sounds like it), you just need to upload them to a folder somewhere inside `pub/media`.

**For example:**

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/media/marketing/example-1.zip
MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/media/marketing/example-2.zip 
MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/media/marketing/example-3.zip
```

**CMS Page Content:**

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="{{media url=marketing/example-1.zip}}">Example 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="{{media url=marketing/example-2.zip}}">Example 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="{{media url=marketing/example-3.zip}}">Example 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am on Magento Enterprise cloud. When I do a git push and pull I do not seem to be able to push/pull from/to the pub folder. Maybe I just need to edit my .gitignore file however is this possible to edit on Magento2 enterprise cloud?

Comment: It is possible on commerce cloud. Pub/media should be writable, but pub/media should not be tracked in your git repo. You'll just manually upload the files

Comment: With Magento cloud, most of the file system is read only, with the exception of a few files and folders (var, app/etc/env.php, pub/media).

Comment: Thank you for the help.